# How can I convert a flash movieclip into a png sequence?

Tags: png, flash-cs4, movieclip

Flash CS4 is not letting me save a swf to a png sequence. Is there a way to save a movieclip as a swf and use an outside program to convert to png?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

File -> Export -> Export Movie... -> PNG Sequence

It's a VERY old Flash feature but luckily it's been left in even up into CS5.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an animated sequence I think the best way, for me anyway, is to import the SWF into after effects, then export as a PNG sequence. Make sure to enable the alpha on export settings if you need transparency too!